# Text placement in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I'm using Tkinter for the GUI of a game and I want to place a letter on top of each grid square (sorry, English is not my first language). The problem is every time that I try to do that, I can't seem to get the position of the letter right.

[image: board]

The picture shows what the code is showing so far (all letters together with very little space in between) and the blue circles show where I want to place the rest of the letters (B,C,D and so on)

Here the code that I used to make the grid:

Size_of_board = 800

```
    def initialize_board(self):
        text = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
        #write the letters on each corner
        #I believe the mistake comes from (i+1)*size_of_board but I'm not sure
        for i in range(8):
            self.canvas.create_text((i+1)*size_of_board / 70, size_of_board / 70, font="cmr 15 bold", fill="black", text=text[i])
        #Grid rows and columns 
        for i in range(7):
            self.canvas.create_line((i + 1) * size_of_board / 8, 0, (i + 1) * size_of_board / 8, size_of_board)
        for i in range(7):
            self.canvas.create_line(0, (i + 1) * size_of_board / 8, size_of_board, (i + 1) * size_of_board / 8)
```

I would really appreciate any help or advice, thank you.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 70, rather than 8 as you are when drawing the grid lines?  You are spacing the letters such that 70 of them would exactly fill the board.

Comment: As @jasonharper said, the problem was the 70. I think I wanted to try with seven and ended up adding an extra number. Works just fine now, thanks!